# How to Connect to SQL server with another System

Tags: c#, sql, remote-server

i just released a program with C# and Visual Studio which has a login form.
This login form has Database and table and you should have user name and password to connect to this program. When you enter Username and password program will connect to the SQL Server (which is in my System) and if username and password was correct you can enter the program.
But when i installed this program in another System , i cannot even enter the program and the error is : Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQl server is configured tp allow remote Connections.
And the error code is 40.
I have set the port of the program to 1433 and changed the TCP/IP to enable and restarted the SQl server.
And already i have added this port to inbound rules in Windows Firewall of Windows.
And in the option of Sql server i have checked : Allow other Systems to connect.
But i cannont Connect to my System , with another Systems.
What is my problem ?
Here is my code of SQL server and Connections Code in C#.

```
int x = tblLoginTableAdapter1.LoginSystem(txtUserName.Text, txtPassWord.Text).Value;
```

and the Connection string :

```
    class Connection
{
    public static  string C = "Data Source=VORTEX;Initial Catalog=Warehouse;Integrated Security=True";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don´t really get where you´re going with this...there is no sense in having a local DB for login.
Nevertheless I´m gonna try answering your question.
You can´t set the connection string in your program because different PC´s have different instance names (duh).

```
class Connection
{
    public static  string C = "Data Source=VORTEX (<=This is your error);Initial Catalog=Warehouse;Integrated Security=True";
}
```

Use the app.config for storing connection strings instead.

So your app.config would then look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add key="data" connectionString="Data Source=VORTEX;Initial Catalog=Warehouse;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And that´s how you get the connection string:

```
var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["data"].ConnectionString;
```

You also have to add a reference to `System.Configuration`